# How do I access a github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go server from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, go, quic

when I ran quic-go-0.18.1(https://github.com/lucas-clemente/quic-go) with command: go run main.go -bind=127.0.0.1:443 -qlog -tcp in dir /example.

1. I use the client to visit https://127.0.0.1/demo/tile, I could get response:(Proto:"HTTP/3"),
2. when I use chrome and chrome beta to visit https://127.0.0.1/demo/tile, I find chrome only use http/1.1 to visit my server.

My Question is : How I can use chrome to visit https://127.0.0.1/demo/tile through HTTP/3?

My environment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Chrome switch on enable-quic.

GO version: 15

Answer (score 1):

reading https://www.chromium.org/quic/quic-faq it says:

> How do I aim Chrome at the test server? If you have an HTTP server,
> you'll need it to emit a response header that looks like:
>
> Alternate-Protocol: quic:< QUIC server port >
>
> Then you can just run chrome as usual and it will automatically start
> using QUIC.
>
> If you're testing only with the toy quic server, you can do something
> like:
>
> % chrome --disable-setuid-sandbox --enable-quic
> --origin-to-force-quic-on=localhost:6121 http://localhost:6121/
>
> If you need help troubleshooting, try running the QUIC server with
> --v=1 or check out playing-with-quic

does it solve your issue ? Please report for others.

Comment: As you see: my server's response header is  

Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000

Content-Length: 10

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Date: Fri, 06 Nov 2020 01:14:42 GMT

I also enable-quic in chrome